# How to plot an elliptic curve using sage

Tags: plot, sage

I want to plot an elliptic curve using sage mathematical interface with the following commands:

```
 E = EllipticCurve([0,0,1,-1,0]);

 Ep = plot(E,-2.5,1,thickness=1);

 show(Ep);
```

However an empty pdf file is launched entitled with 'Sage Graphics object consisting of 2 graphics primitives' and nothing more.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

Weird. I get a plot, both in the console and in the notebook. What interface are you using?

Comment: Sage Version 5.12, on Ubuntu 12.04